# Ransack searchbox in application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Rails 4 app with a a search form on an index page which searches records with Ransack. This all works fine. However, I want to move the search box to the header of the app and therefore move it to the application layout.

But, this results of course in an error, because the Ransack search instance variable is only available on that specicif index page. How can I create this?

Answer (score 0):

If your search is always against the same table you could use a `before_filter` in the ApplicationController.  For example, if the search is always against the `users` table then `application_controller.rb` could have:

```
before_filter :build_search

private
  def build_search
    @search = User.search(params[:q])
  end
```

And `users_controller.rb` could have:

```
def index
  @users = @search.result
end
```